# What is this long string of CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

Working on a frame work file and ran into a long string of css of the likes I've never seen before

```
html body .ow_button:hover .ow_ic_attach{background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width%3D%2220%22%20height%3D%2220%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2020%2020%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20d%3D%22m2.814%2014.583c.083-.731.439-1.411%201.066-2.038l6.144-6.144c1.255-1.233%202.382-1.411%203.385-.532.9.919.521%201.877-.753%203.194l-5.675%205.643-.876-.968%205.611-5.612c.021%200%20.409-.405.482-.5.216-.257.354-.428.141-.675-.252-.272-.633-.007-1.219.579l-6.112%206.113c-.397.376-.617.741-.659%201.098-.042.417.146.836.565%201.254.438.354.81.506%201.112.454.304-.053.685-.299%201.145-.737.877-.856%202.042-2.01%203.495-3.448%201.453-1.441%202.493-2.486%203.12-3.134.021-.021.521-.48%201.034-1.155.374-.49.685-.941.752-1.228.147-.698-.011-1.265-.532-1.975-.521-.71-1.14-1.108-1.851-1.191-.73-.083-1.547.303-2.444%201.16l-6.709%206.709-1.097-1.066%206.709-6.74c1.045-1.024%202.111-1.562%203.198-1.615%201.087-.052%202.1.392%203.04%201.333%201.128%201.149%201.525%202.414%201.191%203.793-.209.794-.71%201.599-1.505%202.414-.92.899-2.236%202.205-3.95%203.919l-3.353%203.352c-.752.751-1.557%201.14-2.414%201.16-.731%200-1.4-.304-2.01-.909-.752-.753-1.097-1.589-1.035-2.508%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E);}
```

Anyone know what on earth is going on here? Where can I learn about whats going on here?

Comment: Decoded the URL looks something like:  http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a technique where a `data URI` is used in place of a normal `URI` in the CSS `background-image:` declaration.

To make matters more confusing, the one above isn't the kind of `data URI` you'd normally expect. (That would be a `base-64` encoded `data URI`... which is an impenetrable and very... very... long... alphanumeric string).

Instead, this is percent-encoded `XML`. (Much simpler!)

It turns out the `XML` markup for `SVG` *can* be included inline "as-is" in the CSS `background-image:` declaration *as long as* the `XML` is percent-encoded.

**Further Reading:**

- https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/ by Chris Coyier
- http://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris by Taylor Hunt

For the sake of completeness, here is the `SVG XML` markup above, ***decoded***:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20">

    <path fill="#fff" d="m2.814 14.583c.083-.731.439-1.411 1.066-2.038l6.144-6.144c1.255-1.233 2.382-1.411 3.385-.532.9.919.521 1.877-.753 3.194l-5.675 5.643-.876-.968 5.611-5.612c.021 0 .409-.405.482-.5.216-.257.354-.428.141-.675-.252-.272-.633-.007-1.219.579l-6.112 6.113c-.397.376-.617.741-.659 1.098-.042.417.146.836.565 1.254.438.354.81.506 1.112.454.304-.053.685-.299 1.145-.737.877-.856 2.042-2.01 3.495-3.448 1.453-1.441 2.493-2.486 3.12-3.134.021-.021.521-.48 1.034-1.155.374-.49.685-.941.752-1.228.147-.698-.011-1.265-.532-1.975-.521-.71-1.14-1.108-1.851-1.191-.73-.083-1.547.303-2.444 1.16l-6.709 6.709-1.097-1.066 6.709-6.74c1.045-1.024 2.111-1.562 3.198-1.615 1.087-.052 2.1.392 3.04 1.333 1.128 1.149 1.525 2.414 1.191 3.793-.209.794-.71 1.599-1.505 2.414-.92.899-2.236 2.205-3.95 3.919l-3.353 3.352c-.752.751-1.557 1.14-2.414 1.16-.731 0-1.4-.304-2.01-.909-.752-.753-1.097-1.589-1.035-2.508"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a so called path. Its coded in a enc language, and it might take a time to decrypt, basicly the numbers after % is a code and means something like space or a special character. Forexample %20 = space... By all i suggest you dont mess around with that code, its copy righted.. If you want to decrypt the cpde take a look at:[charset: ASCII](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

I have decrypted this code for you (look at bottom). This is a svg/ascii code for URL decryption. Heres the decrypted code:

```
image/svg xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20"><path fill="#fff" d="m2.814 14.583c.083-.731.439-1.411 1.066-2.038l6.144-6.144c1.255-1.233 2.382-1.411 3.385-.532.9.919.521 1.877-.753 3.194l-5.675 5.643-.876-.968 5.611-5.612c.021 0 .409-.405.482-.5.216-.257.354-.428.141-.675-.252-.272-.633-.007-1.219.579l-6.112 6.113c-.397.376-.617.741-.659 1.098-.042.417.146.836.565 1.254.438.354.81.506 1.112.454.304-.053.685-.299 1.145-.737.877-.856 2.042-2.01 3.495-3.448 1.453-1.441 2.493-2.486 3.12-3.134.021-.021.521-.48 1.034-1.155.374-.49.685-.941.752-1.228.147-.698-.011-1.265-.532-1.975-.521-.71-1.14-1.108-1.851-1.191-.73-.083-1.547.303-2.444 1.16l-6.709 6.709-1.097-1.066 6.709-6.74c1.045-1.024 2.111-1.562 3.198-1.615 1.087-.052 2.1.392 3.04 1.333 1.128 1.149 1.525 2.414 1.191 3.793-.209.794-.71 1.599-1.505 2.414-.92.899-2.236 2.205-3.95 3.919l-3.353 3.352c-.752.751-1.557 1.14-2.414 1.16-.731 0-1.4-.304-2.01-.909-.752-.753-1.097-1.589-1.035-2.508"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's accessing SVG code from W3.org for use as the background image.  SVG is a vector type of image where, as you can see here, you can pass image info right on the URL.

Comment: That's awesome. It would be nice if you can decode the whole SVG and show it. `:)`

Comment: Nice! Thats awesome!